# Image is stretched vertically while using Glide in Grid View Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-gridview, android-glide

I made an app that displays images stored locally in a grid view.I used to use Picasso but i stopped using it due to many issues(It didn't load images on some devices).Then i switched to glide,everything is fine except that the image is stretched vertically. This causes scrolling issue.I never faced such an issue while using Picasso.How can i fix this issue ???

My MainActivity code-

```
 Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .load(mThumbIds[position])
                    .placeholder(R.raw.place_holder)
                    .error(R.raw.big_problem)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(imageView);
            return imageView;
```

My activity_main.xml file code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="150dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Screenshot of the problem-[See the image on the right it is stretched vertically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvAQd.png)

Answer (score 12):

I just found out.
It's because size of placeholder image didn't match original image.

My solution was simply remove placeholder or resize your placeholder